# find a basis for U?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

find a basis for $U = \operatorname{span}\{(1,2,4) , (2,4,1) ,(3,0,4), (5,0,2)\}$ ?

i dont't know the exact answer , but from point of view this all are linearly independent vector , i know that all linearly independent vector are not always forms a basis . My teacher give this question as a homework. I don't know what to do and also don't know know how to find the basis.
If anybody help me i would be very thankful to him

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

One possible way is to put the $4$ row vectors as rows of a matrix, perform elementary row operations to obtain row echelon forms.

The non-zero rows would be a basis.

Also remark: they are not linearly independent. You can't have more than $3$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: thanks but  what is the basis @ siong thye goh

Comment: you have to do your homework =)

Comment: Hint:Any $3$ vectors from $n$ linearly independent vectors in $R^n$,lies in different planes so they generate the whole space  $R^n$.You just need to find three such vectors to generate  $R^3$,Then you may consider that they forms a basis